# Url pattern matching is confusing in django

Tags: python, django

I have a url.py file as below -

```
app_name = "fronta"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'home/', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'lostform/', views.lostform, name='lostform'),
    url(r'submitlostform/',views.submitlostform, name="submitlostform"),
]
```

I set the action for a form as below -

```
<form  method="post" action="{% url 'fronta:submitlostform'%}">
```

When I click the submit button, url in address bar changes from `http://localhost:8000/fronta/lostform/` to `http://localhost:8000/fronta/submitlostform/` but page is **not** redirected.

However if I change the sequence of urls in urls.py file and move the `url(r'submitlostform/',views.submitlostform, name="submitlostform")` line at top of urls, it works and page is redirected. OR If I change the name of url form `submitlostform` to `lostformsubmit` than also this works.

Why is this happening. I am confused how url pattern matching is working here. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: No javascript. answer by C14L is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions.

```
url(r'lostform/', views.lostform, name='lostform'),
```

This matches `lostform/` but also `123lostform/` and `lostform/123` and `123lostform/321`

Change it to

```
url(r'^lostform/$', views.lostform, name='lostform'),
```

- `^` means "beginning"
- `$` means "end"

Change all your other URL patterns accordingly.

Btw, that's what the first URL pattern means:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

The beginning of the URL `^`, followed by no characters at all, followed by the end `$` of the URL.